# Error Spring Data Neo4j in docker image

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I'm using spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j in my project.
I'm developing under Eclipse on Windows 10 with Java 8.
The neo4j server is in another machine (10.10.10.6).

Under Windows, compile, package and build image is OK. Run image is OK no error.

Under qEmu image of Debian I'm facing an error.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.mapping.RepositoryResourceMappings]: Factory method 'resourceMappings' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PersistentEntity must not be null!
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
   ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PersistentEntity must not be null!
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115) ~[spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
```

My application.yml:

```
spring:
  jackson:
    serialization:
      WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS: false

neo4j:
  user: neo4j
  password: neo4j
  url: http://10.10.10.6:7474/

server:
  port: 8080
```

My configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.referentielneo4j.data.repositories")
@Slf4j
public class Referentielneo4jApplication extends Neo4jConfiguration {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Referentielneo4jApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration getConfiguration() {
        org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration config = new org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration();
        config.driverConfiguration().setDriverClassName("org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver");
        config.driverConfiguration().setURI("http://neo4j:neo4j@10.10.10.6:7474");
        return config;
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return new SessionFactory(getConfiguration(), "com.referentielneo4j.data.model");
    }

    public Session getSession() throws Exception {
        return super.getSession();
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationListener<BeforeSaveEvent> beforeSaveEventApplicationListener() {
        return new ApplicationListener<BeforeSaveEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void onApplicationEvent(BeforeSaveEvent event) {
                Object entity = event.getEntity();
                log.debug("Before save of: " + entity);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationListener<AfterSaveEvent> afterSaveEventApplicationListener() {
        return new ApplicationListener<AfterSaveEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void onApplicationEvent(AfterSaveEvent event) {
                Object entity = event.getEntity();
                log.debug("Before save of: " + entity);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationListener<AfterDeleteEvent> deleteEventApplicationListener() {
        return new ApplicationListener<AfterDeleteEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void onApplicationEvent(AfterDeleteEvent event) {
                Object entity = event.getEntity();
                log.debug("Before save of: " + entity);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>referentielneo4j</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>referentielneo4j</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <ogm.driver.version>2.1.0-SNAPSHOT</ogm.driver.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.voodoodyne.jackson.jsog</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jsog</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-embedded-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
            <!-- <version>{ogm-version}</version> -->
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

My Dockerfile

```
FROM java:openjdk-8-jre-alpine
MAINTAINER XXXXX XXXXX <xxxx.xxxx@gmail.com>

ADD target/referentielneo4j-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/referentielneo4j.jar
ADD application.yml /conf/application.yml

CMD java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app/referentielneo4j.jar --spring.config.location=file:/conf/application.yml --debug

EXPOSE 8080
```

Have you some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't Docker: Neo4J fails to find entities in executable archives.

To workaround this bug you should add a basePackage to you application file like this:

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
   return new SessionFactory(getConfiguration(), "com.referentielneo4j.data.model", "BOOT-INF.classes.com.referentielneo4j.data.model");
}
```

This workaround is explain here [Github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6709)